# Убрать отступы при float:right

Tags: html, css

```css
.clearfix {display: block;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: '';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.fl_l {float: left;}
.fl_r {float: right;}

#tasks_list {background: #cccccc; padding: 15px}
#tasks_list .count {width: 100px}
#tasks_list .price {width: 100px}
#tasks_list .control {width: 150px;}
```

```html
<div id="tasks_list">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="fl_l count">
      123
    </div>
    <div class="fl_l price">
      +5
    </div>
    <div class="fl_r control">
      testtesttest
      <br />
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3q6opaqv/

Когда задаю `width` последней колонке, то появляется свободное место в конце:

[image]

Если же убрать `width` у последней колонки, то всё нормально:

[image]

Каким образом сделать, чтобы при задании `width` последней колонке, места не оставалось?

`text-align: right` отчасти помог, но он некрасиво по правой части выравнивает текст:

[image]

Желательно **не предлагать** изменять `width` у первой и второй колонок, чтобы как-то подвинуть последнюю колонку.

Comment: А если задать `max-width: 150px;`

Comment: может так? - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/75vLo0kx/

Comment: @soledar10, просто гениально. Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, так как Вы ответили первым.

Comment: @soledar10 не видел ваш комментарий, пока писал ответ с небольшими пояснениями. Хотя тут не особо много вариантов... Добавьте ответ и я удалю свой

Comment: @VenZell - главное, что это помогло решить данную проблему. А ответ пусть будет Ваш

Comment: @soledar10, тогда с Вашего разрешения, помечаю вопрос от VenZell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам понадобится обернуть содержимое блока `fl_r control` в блок-обертку.

Как будет выглядеть код:

```
<div class="fl_r control">
  <div class="control_content">      
    testtesttest
    <br />
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Далее, на блок `control` нужно повесить выравнивание текста по правому краю:

```
.control {
  text-align: right
}
```

Далее, чтобы блок `control_content` сместился к правому краю, необходимо сделать его `inline-block` элементом. Главное не забыть вернуть выравнивание текста по левому краю:

```
.control_content {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```css
.clearfix {display: block;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: '';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.fl_l {float: left;}
.fl_r {float: right;}

#tasks_list {background: #cccccc; padding: 15px; margin-top: 60px/*Для демонстрации*/}
#tasks_list .count {width: 100px}
#tasks_list .price {width: 100px}
#tasks_list .control {width: 150px; text-align: right}
#tasks_list .control_content {display: inline-block; text-align: left}
```

```html
<div id="tasks_list">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="fl_l count">
      123
    </div>
    <div class="fl_l price">
      +5
    </div>
    <div class="fl_r control">
      <div class="control_content">
        testtesttest
        <br />
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Посмотреть результат](https://jsfiddle.net/3q6opaqv/2/)

Comment: проголосовал за Ваш ответ. Но чтобы было справедливо, выберу ответ пользователя soledar10, так как он ответил первее. Спасибо большое Вам обоим :)